# Why is adding and removing a fragment giving me memory leak?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am fairly new to android dev so any help is really appreciated!
I am getting this error

> 12-30 08:14:32.391    1726-1741/? E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>       java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
>               at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
>               at java.util.zip.Inflater.(Inflater.java:82)
>               at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.(GzipSource.java:62)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.unzip(HttpEngine.java:645)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>               at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:811)
>               at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:776)
>               at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:676)
>               at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:660)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.j.a(SourceFile:220)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:263)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
>               at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
>               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.al.run(SourceFile:135)

and part of the code that's causing the error

```
 gameLayout.setOnTouchListener(
            new FrameLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    //add bullet upon click
                    bullet_fragment b_fragment = new bullet_fragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.game, b_fragment).commit();

                    //bullet moves around screen (some code here)

                    // removes bullet
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(b_fragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
          g  }
    );
```

so every time the screen is touched a fragment is generated so it's possible for there to be multiples of the same fragment to exist on the screen, which is no problem
I've tried searching a bit and found that remove() doesn't necessarily move the fragment to the GC, but the person didn't say how to completely destroy it. How can I do that then? or is there another reason for that error to occur?

code of the fragment

```
public class bullet_fragment extends Fragment {
View bulletView;

ImageView bulletObject;




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bulletView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bullet_layout, container, true);
    bulletObject = (ImageView) bulletView.findViewById(R.id.bullet);

    return bulletView;

}
public void shoot(int x, int y){
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams b_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(bulletObject.getLayoutParams());


    final int B_WIDTH= (int) (bulletObject.getWidth() * 0.5);
    final int B_HEIGHT= (int) (bulletObject.getHeight() * 0.5);
    b_params.setMargins(x - B_WIDTH,y - B_HEIGHT,0,0);
    bulletObject.setLayoutParams(b_params);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please attach the actual error message and the related code it points to in the fragment?

Comment: ok I added the error message

Comment: this looks more like a bug in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the stacktrace is clearly caused by okhttp but it may not necessarily be the fault of okhttp. The fact that this happens inside gms which is part of Google Services suggests that you likely have nothing to do with the issue. Are you sure this log is for your process and not some system process?

*okhttp reference*

- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1048

*picasso reference (as an example of how a library may be at fault)*

- https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/296

Comment: ok I added the code of the fragment. I honestly don't know what's the issue because the code is really simple

Comment: Updated the answer, I believe you need to filter your logcat by your applications process instead of viewing all logs which is where I assume this trace came from.

Comment: That's the only thing that is running so far, so I'm pretty sure that's the logcat for that specific process. Sorry I'm really new to this and I'm really confused about what's going on.

Comment: Your device is running a minimum of tens of processes. You need to filter your logcat by process of your application which is the default configuration of logcat in Android Studio.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the default then. I somehow managed to fix the error by adding the fragment transaction inside the listener. I don't know why it fixed the problem : p Thank you very much though!